# Stack Remote no Windows

Tags: novo-recurso

Existe alguma possibilidade de sair um Stack Remote para Windows Desktop (Metro UI) ou Windows Phone?

Achei interessante o aplicativo, mas não tenho Android.

Comment: Com base [nesse link](http://stackapps.com/questions/3178/stack-remote-free-android-app-dedicated-towards-stack-exchange-sites). Acredito que no momento a prioridade é iOS e quem sabe depois possa aparecer um para Windows Phone.

Comment: Será que existe a possibilidade de sair para a interface Metro no Windows Desktop? É uma maravilha não depender de navegadores.

Comment: Já existe para a interface metro : http://stackapps.com/questions/3717/stackstabilizer-a-windows-8-metro-stackoverflow-app-version-4-11-09-2012

Comment: O único problema é que para logar na sua conta é preciso pagar 3 dólares.